# How to configure 2 localhosts through wampserver in windows 8?

Tags: localhost, wampserver

I need to run two localhost

1. localhost that runs project from another pc server and
2. localhost1 from my own pc.

How to manage it. I have changed the ip address via host document but it is not working in my pc.

I have windows 8.

Comment: You are a little thin on details. Please explain exactly what you mean by `localhost that runs project from another pc server`

Comment: i mean we have a server pc which contain the project files and i need to access that project using localhost to run on browser. we have different ip.

Comment: I would suggest setting up Virtual Hosts. That way you can have as many sites configured on you local PC as you like, as a Virtual host allows you to define a different DocumentRoot for each VHOST. [See this post for some help setting up Virtual Host on WAMPServer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618) However beware of using server locations as a DocumentRoot, it is best to use a UNC rather than a simple mapped drive i.e. dont use `DocumetRoot "X:/sitecode"` instead setup a UNC and use that.